# Не работает профилирование в VisualStudio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, отладка, профилирование

Я заметил что одна написанная мной функция выполняется довольно медленно. Чтобы узнать, в чем проблема я поставил пару точек остановы, запустил отладку, думал начать смотреть, какие функции занимают больше всего времени а тут получилось, что профайлер может показать только соотношения ресурсоемкости в Main, а если хочешь посмотреть, какой расклад в функция, что я вызываю в Main, то оказывается что дальше тупик.
В представлении Вызывающий/вызываемый Поле вы Вызываемые функции написано Низ стека вызовы, но это точно не так, весь код полностью написан на c# в одном модуле, но почему то в представлении Дерево вызовов у моей исследуемой функции модуль - ManagedModule.
Итого я не могу узнать, почему моя функция, используемая в Main медленная.
Конкретно пишет

```
Не удалось загрузить символы system.linq.dll. Не удалось найти локальный файл символов System.Linq.ni.pdb
Не удалось загрузить символы system.private.corelib.dll. Не удалось найти локальный файл символов System.Private.CoreLib.ni.pdb
```

Как можно заглянуть поглубже? Что не так?

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам смотреть linq и corelib, если проблема в вашей функции.

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то [Specify symbol (.pdb)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не смотрел  linq и corelib. Я просто попытался идти глубже это все что вышло

Comment: Думаю, тут стоит добавить скриншот(ы). Что именно запускается и как выглядит результат в профайлере.